# не запускается бот в реплите на питоне

Tags: python, discord.py

сделал на реплите бота для дискорда своего и теперь такая ошибка вылезла

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 281, in <module>
    bot.run(os.environ['token'])
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
```

реплит у самого же находит ошибки

вот код:
https://replit.com/@jsmodel/ai-discord-py-bot

Comment: отредактируй вопрос и скинь код

Comment: я просто новенький и низнаю как правильно делать вопросы и тд

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask